# PL/SQL Block to show the table details

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL and I need your help..

I was created student table named(students) and inserted 10 rows successfully.
I need to create a block when the user enter the student ID should be show the all details which  match  with the entered student ID.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT inputID PROMPT 'Please enter the student ID to show the details'
DECLARE
B_students students%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT *
  INTO B_students
  FROM students
  WHERE B_students.studentID= inputID;

dbms_output.put_line('Student details : ID:'
                     ||B_students.studentID
                     ||'Student Name'
                     ||B_students.studentName
                     ||'Student GPA'
                     ||B_students.studentGPA
                     ||'Student AGE'
                     ||B_students.studentAGE
                     ||'Student Gender'
                     ||B_students.studentGender);

END;
```

The error report :
"inputID": invalid identifire
PL/SQL: SQL Statment ignored
06550.00000 -"line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*cause: usually a PL/SQL compilation error

Comment: Where are you running this? `ACCEPT` is supported in`SQL*Plus` only.

Comment: SQL developer .. is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. This syntax is specific to SQLPlus.

Comment: How I can create a Block to show the student details in the SQL developer?

Comment: If you are running this in SQL Developer, why have you tagged PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: @GMB - incorrect.  The ACCEPT command, just like most if not all sqlplus commands, is fully implemented in SQL Developer as well.  Try it for yourself and see.  The OP's problem is not the ACCEPT command in SQL Dev, but rather his improper reference to the input variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the identifier `inputID` is declared in SQL*Plus and your PL/SQL block cannot directly see it. To use it you need to precede it with an `&` character:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT inputID PROMPT 'Please enter the student ID to show the details'

DECLARE
  B_students students%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT *
    INTO B_students
    FROM students
    WHERE B_students.studentID = &inputID;

  dbms_output.put_line('Student details : ID:'
                       ||B_students.studentID
                       ||'Student Name'
                       ||B_students.studentName
                       ||'Student GPA'
                       ||B_students.studentGPA
                       ||'Student AGE'
                       ||B_students.studentAGE
                       ||'Student Gender'
                       ||B_students.studentGender);

END;
/
```

Note the use of `&inputID` instead of `inputID` in the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

A function containing `SYS_REFCURSOR` might be created :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_std_rs( i_ID students.studentID%TYPE ) 
                    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT *
              FROM students
             WHERE studentID = :inputID';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql USING i_ID;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then invoked from SQL Developer's Command Line :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := get_std_rs(123);
PRINT rc;
```

- `INTO` Clause cannot be used for multiple returned rows, but one row
  only
- Through the above method, no need to specify all returning columns individually